My java code is stuck in loop when it should end, i put a while that cant exit is condition
I was asked to write a java method executeInParallel that executes without active waiting and without race conditions(so i thought that i needed an ArrayBlockingQueue).I was also asked to not   use other classes than the ones already in my code
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class ParallelExecutor {
    public static void executeInParallel(Runnable[] runnables, int K) {
        if (K <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't execute zero or less concurrent runnables");
        if (runnables == null || runnables.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide something to run");

        ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(K); // Extra space for end markers

        // Start the producer
        Thread producer = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (Runnable r : runnables) {
                    taskQueue.put(r); // Put a runnable in the queue
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        producer.start();

        // Start the consumer threads
        K=Math.min(runnables.length,K);
        Thread[] consumers = new Thread[K];
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
            consumers[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Runnable r;
                    while((r= taskQueue.take())!=null){
                        r.run();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // Handle exceptions as needed
                }
            });
            consumers[i].start();
        }

        // Wait for the producer to finish
        try {
            producer.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        // Wait for all consumers to finish
        for (Thread consumer : consumers) {
            try {
                consumer.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example usage
        Runnable[] tasks = new Runnable[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            tasks[i] = () -> {
                System.out.println("Task " + index + " is running.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulate work that takes 1 second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                System.out.println("Task " + index + " is finished.");
            };
        }
        executeInParallel(tasks, 3); // Execute tasks in parallel, 3 at a time
    }
}

and the code loops in this part after all the r.run are executed:
 while((r= taskQueue.take())!=null){
       r.run();
    }

How i can remove the loop without adding active wait(i need passive waiting and i was asked to not add other classes like ExecutorService etc.)?
I tried removing the while with something else but i was asked to have k run in parallel so i cant do it without more threads i think

You can use wait and notify to signal the processing or interruption of a thread. For more details, refer to the inter-thread communication example at https://www.javatpoint.com/inter-thread-communication-example.

but isn't better to use ArrayBlockingQueue methods that are thread -safe?  i dont want race conditions on my code

Try making a simple piece of code that splits an array of 20 into blocks of three.  I think you will not need a while loop.

i want to maintan the propriety that when a r.run ends another r.run instantly happens like in my original code, the only problem is the loop for now

Why are you calling run() instead of start? Or even consumers[i] = new Thread(taskQueue.take());

The taskQueue.take() may wait forever until the new task put in the taskQueue ,here is the source code:
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            while (count == 0)
                // continue waiting
                notEmpty.await();
            return dequeue();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

so consider using taskQueue.poll(0,TimeUnit.SECONDS), so it could immediately return task or null.

In the consumers the call taskQueue.take() only returns when a new work item is available.
The producer produces a limited amount of work items and then stops. The consumers however never notice that the producer is no longer active and dutifully wait for new work items, never ending the wait (and therefore never ending).
You can solve this by giving the consumers a maximum wait time, for example by using taskQueue.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
